# Why is alias not available in /etc/profile?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I put `alias se='sudo -E '` in `/etc/profile` and  rebooted. Then I typed `se` and terminal just said "command not found".

Why is alias not available in /etc/profile? How to solve it?

EDIT:

I have tried put `alias se='sudo -E '` in `/etc/profile`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`

- `/etc/profile` failed
- `/etc/zprofile` failed
- `/etc/zshenv` successful
- `/etc/zshrc` successful
- `~/.zprofile` failed
- `~/.zshrc` successful

REF:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `/etc/profile`, i am assuming that you are looking to do this only for login sessions of shell (`zsh`).

That's because `zsh` *by default* does not read `/etc/profile` when starting a login shell. For setting any global parameter for *only* login shells, use the file `/etc/zsh/zprofile`.

For setting something applicable on any sort of invocation, use `/etc/zsh/zshenv` instead. The typical/generic order is `zshenv > zprofile > zshrc > zlogin` (depending on invocation and availability).

Needless to say, for any user specific parameter you should use the user specific `.zprofile` i.e. `~/.zprofile` instead.

---

**Notes:**

- If you are looking to do this for any interactive shell session, use `.zshrc` (`/etc/zshrc` or `~/.zshrc`)
- If you are looking at using a common `/etc/profile`  (or similar), `source` (`.`) `/etc/profile` from the relevant file for `zsh`.

Comment: zsh will read the `/etc/profile`. You can `cat /etc/zprofile` and "source /etc/profile" found in the file.

Comment: Thx for your kind answer and forgive my ignorance about the login shell and interactive shell.